# Twilio Python : Get participants in completed Conference

Tags: python, twilio

I have been trying to get all calls that were in particular conference. What I do is select calls by conference id like this,

```
calls = client.calls.list(conferenceid="thiswillbevalidconferenceid")
```

I tried with `conferenceid` and `conference_id` but its not working.

Is it even possible to get calls by conference id which is completed?

Please note, this is just demo so I am not using any database. Just simple Twilio API calls.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there's no way to get the participants of a conference call that has completed.

The [Conference resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference) in the REST API does have a [Participants List resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list), but that only lists participants that are currently connected to the call.

If you do need this data, I recommend you take a look at the recently launched [Conference events](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/introducing-conference-events.html) which will allow you to receive webhooks when participants join and leave a conference so that you can store that data yourself.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for replying. What I did - saving sid, To, From, Conf when generating calls. And then updated same with status_callback. Its just I had to setup whole mysql thing for this. Everything else was working fine with Twilio API. :)